# Annoying neighbours, barely audible sounds but still very annoying. Sensitivity being important, in my question

Tags: noise

I have got a question. I'm having problems with a neighbour. And I want to record the sounds he's making that are audible to me but especially annoying cause of the nature of the sound, not the loudness or anything.

Actually I believe it's now gotten to a point where it's almost impossible to hear. But yeah I still hear it and it's extremely annoying. If you want to know it's like this cartoon sound of a... might sound weird... but a spring releasing... like this coiled thing that can also be in cars or something. Very cartoonish as I said so it's pretty much annoying anyway, in the way it's used.

I can't make the sound myself accurately. And I need people to hear it how it actually sounds to me to give them an impression of how annoying this actually is. And yeah maybe use it as proof.

It can really disrupt my sleep if I happen to catch it when awake for a moment. It just keeps on repeating from that point on... usually until I get up (and yeah that makes me think how do they know when I get up, but yeah apparently they are aware of all those things, and can give you an idea on how bad this has gotten).

Anyway, so I'm searching for the right kind of equipment for this.

But all I'm finding is music stuff. For singing or instruments or whatever. Occassionally equipment to do with podcast and voice recording like normal instead of singing.

But I can barely find anything at all about noise disturbance, and if I find something on it it's not aimed at barely audible sounds. But instead, really loud noises that you want to measure in some way. But mine is getting like really subtle to the point that you're asking yourself am I imagining it now?? But I'm almost sure that it's just gone really quietly recently... and yeah. So I want to make sure. So in essence I'm trying to find equipment just as sensitive as the human ear can be. As a starting point. And then maybe even more sensitive. So when I'm in doubt about my own hearing, I can get confirmation  from the more sensitive equipment. And I can rule out me imagining things.

By the way, just on alternative solutions you might think of:
I could try using earplugs obviously in this case. But yeah they really seem to adapt to anything I try to counter with so yeah... I thought this... If I can cover my own hearing, that would be a permanent solution. But yeah don't know how pricey that would get. I have found some options of hiring equipment but I need it for a longer period... and maybe it even stops when I have it. Could be possible, they seem to know a lot. So maybe if they know I've got equipment now, they can no longer do it. So maybe I won't be able to record anything and it just prevents noise from that point on. That's why I really think I need to own that kind of equipment instead of hiring it.

Would really appreciate some advice on this. Or some leads cause it's pretty hard to find anything on it. Maybe names of types of equipment like what kind of keywords to search for. Found something on binaural recording, but that really easily goes into this quality type of thing that it's also used for instruments and music etc. It doesn't need to be that good or accurate or nice-sounding. I just need it to be sensitive enough and... it doesn't have to be of perfect musical quality if you get what I'm saying (hoping I can drive down the costs with that a bit in case it will mean something expensive).

I do have some budget for it though so it doesn't have to be extremely cheap either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any noise that stops when you get up is either in your bed or in your head. I'd consider the latter. Any microphone sensitive enough to hear that will also be sensitive enough to pick up every other sound too, like your breathing, traffic passing, wind, the house, plumbing  & bed creaking, and the sound you're looking for will still be as far below intelligibility as it was when it was quiet. Wear ear plugs. if it goes away, great. If it doesn't, re-read my first two sentences.

Comment: That's a pretty weird comment actually. Because it's some added information, context. I don't put it up to discussion. And actually in this case as well, I could record it, then let you hear it, and then you would probably change your mind as well. I get more of those reactions, but that's actually why I need to record it.

Of course it could be difficult, somewhat. But it's often at night or early morning and I'm silent then and there's much less noise then anyway. I think it could pick it up. It's my only shot.

Comment: let's tackle this from two sides. 1) I'm a pro sound engineer. I once had a similar issue [eventually turned out to be my neighbours heating system, he since fixed it] & with all the many thousands of pounds' worth of recording equipment I have access to, I was unable to record the noise with sufficient intelligibility to identify it. The solution was to go round to the neighbour & try things out until we got a match. 2) if the sound disappears when you get up… we're back to my last comment.

Comment: Right okay, that does give me some more info. Thanks. Because I asked somewhere and they said it's quite easy to capture audible sounds. But that was probably from a frequency range perspective like how pitched the sound is. But actually how subtle it is is apparently a different thing. And now you say that it can be quite difficult. It's good to know that.

The only solution left is combine the few... earplugs, and if it gets louder than that could block... it should be easier to capture as well. That's the only way I guess. But it is an option.

Comment: Don't have a way of marking that as a solution but yeah. It does answer my question.

Comment: Have you tried talking to them?

Comment: Yeah I did, he denies pretty much everything although I can actually be 100% sure of some stuff at least uhm yeah.